# The import com.oracle cannot be resolved

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting "the import com.oracle cannot be resolved".

These are my import statements:

```
package com.ecommerce.dao;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;
import com.ecommerce.database.Database;
import com.ecommerce.entity.Account;
import com.ecommerce.entity.CartProduct;
import com.ecommerce.entity.Order;
import com.ecommerce.entity.Product;
import com.oracle.wls.shaded.org.apache.xpath.operations.Or;
```

I have tried adding the ojdbc11 jar file as Oracle JDBC driver, I added it as an external jar file but getting the same error.

Comment: The error suggests that the driver JAR is not actually on your compiletime classpath. That said, in general user code should not have any need to directly import a JDBC `Driver` class. You either access it with `DriverManager`, and if you have to load it explicitly, you'd use the class name with `Class.forName`, not reference the class itself, or you'd use a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 2):

package com.oracle is not part of jdbc jar, so adding jdbc jar (ojdbc11.jar) will not help. You need to add correct jar file in your class-path.